# The icon for your application is not valid. Please use a 48x48 png. Error when uploading .apk

Tags: android, google-play

When I try to upload my application to the market I get the error: "The icon for your application is not valid. Please use a 48x48 png". I have browsed on the internet, but only as anwear. Some of they says something about a "/n" in the values. Does somebody know what that means? I have also shecked that the file acctualy is PNG and the right size.

This is my first application and I need help fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your manifest file doesn't contain any references to strings which contain `\n`

Source: http://my-instinct-was-wrong.com/2011/02/26/the-icon-for-your-application-is-not-valid-please-use-a-48x48-png/