# Google Play Store Upload Symbol Error

Tags: android, google-play

since more than 2 weeks by now I am trying to upload a new version of my app to the google play store. For some reason, it always gives me this error:

First I thought I signed the app with a wrong key, but I always used the same one for that app. So that should not be the problem.

Did anyone of you experience this before and knows how to solve it?

Thank you! http://s7.directupload.net/file/d/3399/qd3qm9bm_png.htm

Comment: If you post the error text in your question in English, you will likely get a larger set of people able to help you.

Comment: "Please check the icon on the APK file. It is not valid."

Comment: Is your icon a PNG file? Does it appear to be corrupted? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9358961/1253844) suggests that having `\n` in your strings.xml may also cause that error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your android manifest.XML and locate your android:versionCode and android:versionName. Your probably may revolve around the fact that you didn't not update your version Code. If your previous app was let's say android:version code="1" update it to 2. And set a new versionName as well. Just make sure each and every time before you upload a update that you increase your versionCode by 1. You can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware that I need to update both the version name and code. I updated it for both manifest.xml files to 1.2 (my first version was code 1.1). Also did I try to upload it as a complete new app (with a changed the package name), even then I could not upload it. Do you maybe have another idea?